# React navigation button behind transparent header not clickable

Tags: react-native, button, header, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a component that when scrolling a button remains at the same height as the header, that header has headerBackTitleVisible: true, and when pressing those buttons in that position, they do not work.
I have tried with headerMode to float or to screen but I still can't find the solution

Comment: Add some of your relevant code in between code tags to the question so it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution for your problem by any chance?

Comment: I'd suggest just hiding the header with `options={{headerShown: false}}`. The button should be clickable after that